# unable to take IPA from xcode build step to App Center Distribute step, but Publish Artifact works

Tags: xcode, azure-devops

I have an xCode build task (version 5) that builds and signs without error. I can then use the publish artificats step to be able to manually download the file from the pipeline.

I need to publish this file to app center though, but even when using the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\filename.ipa` - it's unable to find the file.

I have tried running a bash script to find the file `ls -R`, but I haven't been able to locate where the file is placed that the xcode step is building.

Error from App Center:

> [error]Error: Cannot find any file based on /Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/1/s/filename.ipa

Comment: Hi @user12492959 How was this case going, Did you check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any question

Answer (score 0):

Did you specifically copy or stored the ipa file in folder $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)? the pipeline task would not find the ipa file if it didnot exist in folder your specified.

You can check the **archive path** parameter for Xcode task. The ipa file is placed in the folder defined in **archive path**. You can specify a place to store the ipa file. For below example i place the ipa file in folder `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/archive`. Then in the following task I will refer to the ipa file by the path `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/archive/*.ipa`

[image]

If you leave the archive path to its default value. You can refer to the ipa file with wild-cards `**\*.ipa` which means the pipeline will search all the file with ipa extension within current working folder.

You can also check the xcode pipeline example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops).